# How do you set "max_allowed_packet" in XAMPP?

Tags: mysql

I've changed it in xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini and still, the effect does not show after restarting MySQL. If I run the following command, it works:

```
mysql --max_allowed_packet=512M -u root < .\db\dropUser.sql
```

But, when I browse pages with Drupal, my limit is back to 1Mb, despite the fact that my my.ini file has the value 512 in it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Was going to delete this, but I figured I'd share the answer. Despite what I said above, I changed the ini file again, this time altering the file to have these two values:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 512M

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 512M
```

Previously I had only altered one of the two. *sigh*

Comment: On Xubuntu 16.04 with XAMPP (lampp) is here: `/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: On Windows, this is located at C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini for those interested. Make sure to reboot the database server, and for good measure, go ahead and do it for the web server too.